# How to add existing database context variable to services

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET core service and inside our ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method currently we do something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
..................................................
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

However, I would like to achive something like:

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
.UseSqlServer(connectionString);                
var datbaseContext = new DatabaseContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(use already existinge variable datbaseContext);
```

If I write something like:

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(context => new DatabaseContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
```

the code for sure would compile but then I can't use that context in classes that should be instantinated using that context, e.g.

```
var reminders = new List<IReminder> {new WeeklyReminder(databaseContext), new ApproverReminder(databaseContext)};
```

Is there an easy way to achieve it, or I'm doing something in a very wrong way? I remember it was possible with other DI containers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my colleague helped to find an answer.
Basically just needed to change a service that uses those reminders to create it's own scope and operate with service provider, so the whole could looks as follows:

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
services.AddScoped<IReminder, WeeklyReminder>();
services.AddScoped<IReminder, ApproverReminder>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, EmailSenderHostedService>();
```

...........................................................................

```
public EmailSenderHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
```

........................................

```
foreach (var reminder in _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IReminder>())
```